# How can I get good errors from the LESS compiler when integrated in Symfony 2

Tags: css, symfony, less

I'm using [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) as an app framework and i've integrated dynamic compilation of [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) scripts to CSS for each page refresh. This is the guide i followed:

http://www.kiwwito.com/article/less-css-with-assetic-and-symfony-2

Everything seems to work fine but when i have an error in a LESS script all compilation fails and no CSS is delivered to the browser.

How can i get feedback from the LESS compiler about what went wrong? Are there any logs written anywhere to help debugging LESS scripts with Symfony?

Comment: You can try compiling the problematic file on the command line with `lessc`, which will give detailed error messages.

Comment: Yeah, but it would be nice to tail the errors while they happen during a refresh as there will potentially be a lot of less files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In developer mode Symfony writes a developer log here which contains less errors along with other feedback.

```
app/logs/dev.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Running `app/console assetic:dump` should help.